# Reaction of 1,1-diphenylethanol on Montmorillonite K10 under microwave radiation

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

> What is the product of 1,1-diphenylethanol + Montmorillonite K10 Clay undergoing microwave radiation? What is the mechanism for it?

**My effort**:

1,1-diphenylethanol + Montmorillonite K10 Clay catalyst used in a microwave-assisted synthesis of pyrazoles from enaminones.

Used for:

- Support for catalysts
- Preparation of clay nanopaper composites of nacre-like structure

Catalyst for:

- Conversion of triose sugars with alcohols to alkyl lactates
- Deprotection of ketone dimethylhydrazones

Is my answer correct?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Montorillonite K10 is a solid acid catalyst and microwave is a source of heat, so... $$\ce{Ph2C(OH)CH3 ->[\ce{H+}][\Delta]}?$$

Answer (score 2):

> Is my answer correct?

No! Your "answer" is just a random collection of facts and does not address the question.

Actually, *Ben Norris* has already kindly provided all the necessary information in his comment:

1. Montmorillonite K10 is a solid, acidic catalyst.
2. Microwave irradiation means that you are applying heat to the reaction.

[image: Formation of 1,1-diphenylethene from 1,1-diphenylethanol]

Under the given conditions, 1,1-diphenylethanol (**1**) is protonated, eliminates water (which might be driven out since heat is applied) and yields 1,1-diphenylethene (**2**).

Given that you're still applying heat in the presence of an acidic catalyst, the reaction will not stop here.

Protonation of **2** again results in the known bisbenzylic cation, which will add to a second molecule of 1,1-diphenylethene in *Markovnikov* fashion.

[image: Dimerisation of 1,1-diphenylethene]

The resulting intermediate is will undergo an intramolecular *Friedel-Crafts* alkylation which furnishes the indane derivative **3**.